# Data not Saving into pivot table using Laravel Api Resource

Tags: php, laravel

please I am new to Laravel, I want to use Laravel API Resource to store database inside database.

I have 3 Tables

- Users
- Category
- Category_User (**this is a pivot table**)

In my Controller (`OnboardsControllers`), I have this to store data

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
          $category_user = Category_User::firstOrCreate(
            [
              'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
              'category_id' => $request->$category->id,
            ],
          );

          return new CategoryUserResource($category_user);
    }
```

In my `CategoryUserResource` I have this

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'category_id' => $this->category_id,
            'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
      ];
```

In my Pivot Table, I have this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In my model, I added this

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'category_id', 
];
```

In my `route/api`

```
Route::post('/category_user', 'OnboardsController@onboardupdate');
```

I believe the error is here

```
'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
```

When I removed it, it didn't returned any error

When I tried to save to my database using Postman to test,  it not saving. Please, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: *it returned an error* What error are you getting?

Comment: Its not saving rather

Comment: `$request->$category` is not doing what you think it is. Try `$request->category`

Comment: Still the same, 

It's returned error 

ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you do not need a model `Category_User` (but you need a table).

In Laravel a more concise approach is used:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->input('user_id'));
    $user->categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));
}
```

Also I'm not sure if you have declared a method `categories()` in model `User`:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

I also strongly doubt the existence of method `user()` of class `Request`.

If the request parameter has a name `category_id`, then you need to access it like this:

```php
$request->input('category_id');
```